# Multiple Text Box Validation

Tags: jquery

I need to validate multiple text-boxes, which share a common name

Example

```
<input type="text" name="value[]" />
<input type="text" name="value[]" />
<input type="text" name="value[]" />
```

How can I validate each and every text box, using jQuery? I am using jQuery Validation Plugin

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate fields named with brackets you'll have to quote the name when setting up the rules for the plugin, like this:

```
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
           "value[]": "required"
        }
    });
```

Hope this works for you, if it doesn't please try to specify the rules you want to validate.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form_id").validate({
    rules: {
        "value[]":{
            required: true
            }   
    },
    messages: {
        setting: '<br>'+"Required Field"+''
    }});
</script>
```